# How to get max values valid from and to dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server: how to get maxvalues from and to date information based on below table?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[itemdetails]
(
    [itemid] [int] NULL,
    [maxcost] [money] NULL,
    [startdate] [date] NULL,
    [enddate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[itemdetails] ([itemid], [maxcost], [startdate], [enddate]) 
VALUES (1, 180.0000, CAST('2016-10-03' AS Date), CAST('2016-10-30' AS Date)),
       (1, 142.0000, CAST('2016-10-31' AS Date), CAST('2016-12-27' AS Date)),
       (1, 142.0000, CAST('2016-12-28' AS Date), CAST('2017-01-05' AS Date)),    
       (1, 142.0000, CAST('2017-01-06' AS Date), CAST('2017-01-31' AS Date)), 
       (1, 156.0000, CAST('2017-02-01' AS Date), CAST('2017-02-15' AS Date)),
       (1, 156.0000, CAST('2017-02-16' AS Date), CAST('2017-02-18' AS Date)),  
       (1, 194.0000, CAST('2017-02-19' AS Date), CAST('2017-02-26' AS Date)), 
       (2, 200.0000, CAST('2017-02-02' AS Date), CAST('2017-03-30' AS Date)),
       (2, 210.0000, CAST('2017-03-31' AS Date), CAST('2017-05-05' AS Date)),
       (1, 180.0000, CAST('2017-02-27' AS Date), CAST('2017-03-28' AS Date))
GO
```

Based on above data I want output like below:

```
itemid | maxcost | startdate  | enddate
-------+---------+------------+-----------
  1    | 180.00  | 2016-10-03 | 2016-10-30
  1    | 142.00  | 2016-10-31 | 2017-01-31
  1    | 156.00  | 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-18
  1    | 194.00  | 2017-02-19 | 2017-02-26
  2    | 200.00  | 2017-02-02 | 2017-03-30
  2    | 210.00  | 2017-03-31 | 2017-05-05
  1    | 180.00  | 2017-02-27 | 2017-03-28
```

I tried like this:

```
select  
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by itemid, maxcost order by startdate) as rn 
from  
    itemdetails
where 
    rn = 1
```

but this query does not return the expected result.

Please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: Your expected output seems to be min start date and max end date so I am unclear how this equates to 'how to get maxvalues from and to date information'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the query provided by Michał Turczyn, to consider the periods, not the physical order of the rows.

Consider what if the sample data included also the following row (added after the existing ones):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.itemdetails (itemid, maxcost, startdate, enddate)
VALUES (2, 210.0000, CAST('2017-05-06' AS Date), CAST('2017-05-30' AS Date))
```

I guess that the OP wanted to group this row together with the other rows having itemid=2 and maxcost=210 (even if another row regarding a different product was insterted between those two rows).

Therefore, I propose the following query:

```
SELECT itemid, maxcost, MIN(startdate) AS GroupStartDate, MAX(enddate) AS GroupEndDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(DifferentGroup) OVER (ORDER BY a.itemid, startdate) AS GroupingCol
    FROM (
        SELECT *, 
                CASE WHEN startdate=DATEADD(DAY,1,lag(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY startdate))
                    AND maxcost=LAG(maxcost) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY startdate)
                  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DifferentGroup
        FROM [dbo].[itemdetails]
    ) a
) a GROUP BY itemid,maxcost,GroupingCol
ORDER BY a.itemid, GroupStartDate
```

I guess the row with the startdate='2017-01-02' is a mistake in the sample data and the expected results (it should have been '2017-02-01' in my opinion).

**EDIT:** Here is another solution that works on SQL Server 2008:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY startdate) AS RowNum
        FROM [dbo].[itemdetails]
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT t1.*, CASE WHEN t1.startdate=DATEADD(DAY,1,t2.enddate)
                AND t1.maxcost=t2.maxcost
                THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DifferentGroup
    FROM CTE1 t1
    LEFT JOIN CTE1 t2 ON t2.itemid=t1.itemid AND t2.RowNum = t1.RowNum-1
)
SELECT itemid, maxcost, MIN(startdate) AS GroupStartDate, MAX(enddate) AS GroupEndDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        (SELECT MAX(Q2.RowNum) FROM CTE2 q2 
        WHERE q2.itemid=q1.itemid AND q2.RowNum<=q1.RowNum AND q2.DifferentGroup=1) AS GroupingCol
    FROM CTE1 q1
) a GROUP BY itemid,maxcost,GroupingCol
ORDER BY a.itemid, GroupStartDate
```

I have avoided the call of the `LAG` function by joining on `t2.RowNum = t1.RowNum-1` and the `SUM() OVER` by using a subquery with a `q2.RowNum<=q1.RowNum` condition.

Comment: Iam using sql server 2008 version.its not working lag funcationality.can you please tell me any alternative solution for this task. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic that you requested requires adding extra grouping column. Take a look at the following query (which returns all requested rows, but in different order):

```
select itemid, maxcost, min(startdate), max(enddate) from (
    select *,
           sum(sameGroup) over (order by (select null) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) [GroupingCol]
    from (
        select *, case when lag(itemid) over (order by (select null)) = itemid and lag(maxcost) over (order by (select null)) = maxcost
                  then 0 else 1 end [sameGroup] 
        from [dbo].[itemdetails]
    ) a
) a group by itemid,maxcost,GroupingCol
```

Comment: Your query does not return the last line in the expected result. It seems srinivasa needs to group together the rows only when the periods are adjacent to each other (it's not enough that they have the same itemid and maxcost).

Comment: @RazvanSocol Sample data OP provided didn't include extra row with `maxcost=180`. But thank you for remark and obviously, corrected query :)

Comment: Your modified query seems to consider the physical order of the rows (due to the `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`. I guess the grouping should be done when the periods are adjiacent (based on startdate and enddate), regardless of the physical order of the rows.

Comment: @RazvanSocol I think you're right, but it also seems that records are written to table chronologically, so physical order is identitcal :) But of course, you are right again :) +1

Comment: Iam using sql server 2008 version.its not working lag funcationality.can you please tell me any alternative solution for this task. Thanks!